# how to add a new c++ class that inherits from QThread in a Qt widget application

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I was trying to follow a youtube tutorial video from "voidRealm".

The instructor wanted to add a new class `MyThread` that inherits from `QThread`. He entered the new C++ class wizard, and filled it like this:

[image: Old version of Qt Creator]

Apparently, this wizard has changed in newer versions of Qt Creator. Here is what I get when I open it:

[image: Newer version of Qt Creator]

As you can see from the screenshots, the *"Type Information"* field is missing in the new version of Qt Creator. So, How can I add a new C++ class that inherits from `QThread` (taking into account that `QThread` inherits from `QObject`)?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for the site's standards for asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the addition of the new wizard engine in [Qt Creator 3.3.0](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/dist/changes-3.3.0?h=3.3#n14) (see Qt blog post about Qt creator 3.3.0 release [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/12/10/qt-creator-3-3-0-released/)), the *"type information"* option is no longer available for custom classes.

The new wizard engine allows users to write their custom wizards in `JSON` format. You can see the manual [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards-json.html).

Since all you need is just a basic C++ class (and no `.ui` form has to be generated), A quick workaround would be setting the the *"Base Class"* to `QObject` in the wizard.

[image: screenshot]

And after the new files are generated, you can edit the generated class to make it inherit from `QThread` instead of `QObject`. Since you are new to Qt, here is a list of what you need to do:

1. Add `#include <QThread>` to `mythread.h` file.
2. Change `class MyThread : public QObject` to `class MyThread : public QThread` in `mythread.h` file.
3. in `mythread.cpp` file, change `MyThread::MyThread(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)` to `MyThread::MyThread(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)`.

---

#### side notes:

- This is just a quick workaround (It is not the best solution to the problem). A more general solution would be creating your own *better* custom wizard that supports inheriting from `QThread`.
- Please note that there are many ways to do multi-threading in Qt without subclassing `QThread`. Worker objects are generally more preferable see [here](https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage), You can also take a look at [this post](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) from the Qt blog.